# How to make it so that only OPs can trigger command blocks?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have googled everywhere and can't find the answer.

I have command blocks on a vanilla server to give players items for minigames. I want these command blocks to only be executable by someone with OP permissions. Is this possible?

From what I can read it was like this back in 1.4.2, meaning there must be a config setting somewhere?

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Only OPs can edit or place command blocks and execute commands from chat. But command blocks can always be activated with redstone and it was that way since they were added to the game. To prevent that, you would have to track who activated a redstone circuit, which is pretty much impossible.

Comment: I guess you could make a function that replaces the blocks around the command block with air every tick. That way OPs could still click it, set it to "always active" and then back again. But the question is: Why would you want that?

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to give all the OP players a [scoreboard tag](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Scoreboard#Tags):

```
/scoreboard players tag <entity> add <tagName>
```

Replace `<entity>` with the OP player's name and replace `<tagName>` with the tag you want them to have.  You will have to do this manually for each of your OP players.  Here is an example:

```
scoreboard players tag IronAnvil add ImOP
```

Now you can specify [target selector arguments](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#Target_selector_arguments) to test for this tag.  This combined with a [radius](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#Selecting_targets_by_radius) argument can test for a tagged player close to the block.

One upside to doing it this way is that you don't have to move or change your current command blocks.  You only have to change the [target selector](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#Target_selectors) in the current give commands.  You would use the target selector:

```
@a[tag=<tagName>,r=R]
```

Replace `<tagName>` with tag you gave the players with the first command.  Replace `R` with the desired radius from the command block.  This target selector is used within your current give commands.  Here is an example:

```
give @a[tag=ImOP,r=3] minecraft:diamond_sword 1 0
```

This would only give an item to a player with the tag ImOP who is within the radius of the command block.  If a non tagged player activates the command block and there are no tagged players within the radius of that command block, the command block with output that the "Selector '@a[tag=ImOP,r=3]' found nothing."  If a non tagged player activates the command block and there happens to be a tagged player within the radius it will give the item to the tagged player not the non tagged player.

You can then remove the tag if you ever want to with:

```
/scoreboard players tag <entity> remove <tagName>
```